# Expo / Fastlane: Problem giving the path to my provisioning profile

Tags: react-native, app-store, expo, provisioning-profile, fastlane

I want to publish a React Native app created with Expo (which uses fastlane under the hood) to Apple's AppStore.

During the [process](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps/) I select

```
I will provide all the credentials and files needed, Expo does limited validation
```

I give all the file paths and credentials until I get the prompt:

```
? Path to .mobile provisioning profile:
```

I try to answer this by typing in:

```
/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/<uuid>.mobileprovision
```

but it just displays the same prompt again (`? Path to .mobile provisioning profile:`). I assume it thinks the path is invalid.

How do you add your own provisioning profile when uploading an Expo app?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Expo doesn't handle backslashes/escaping correctly. Try `/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/<uuid>.mobileprovision` instead.